# Twin Primes of the form $3k-1, 3k+1$

Tags: prime-numbers, twin-primes

I wanted to discuss something.
Yesterday I thought about the twin prime conjecture and I constructed numbers of the form
$$
3k-1, 3k, 3k+1
$$
Then I proved with the help of quadratic reciprocity, that there are inifinitely many prime numbers of the form $3k+1$. I plugged in some even numbers for $k$ and I thought, that if $3k+1$ is prime, then $3k-1$ has to be prime, hasn't it? - No, because $3\cdot 12+1=37,$ which is prime but $35=5\cdot 7$ surely isn't. I was disappointed but nevertheless I figured that there are quite a lot of prime pairs $3k-1,3k+1$. Is there a way to prove or contradict this? If so, we would have infinitely many twin primes, wouldn't we? Maybe we have to find more conditions so that this pair of numbers is really prime.

Comment: If you think about it a minute, you'll realize that all twin prime pairs, other than $(3,5)$, must have the form $(6k-1,6k+1)$.  Nobody knows if there are infinitely many or not.

Comment: For large $k$, how do you expect even one of the numbers to be prime ? The pair $6k\pm 1$ rules out only the prime factors $2$ and $3$ , even $5$ is a possible prime factor of exactly one of the numbers. Additionally, do you think the twin prime conjecture would be an open problem if THIS discovery would be the key to solve it ?

Comment: Do not make the mistake to look only for small numbers ! Small numbers are often prime , in particular if $2$ and $3$ is no prime factor. Unfortunately, there is no construction method even for a single very large prime , let alone for a twin prime pair.